# MovieLens data set

Tags: dataset, pandas

I want to analyze [MovieLens data set](http://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/) and load on my machine the M1 file. I combine actually two data files (ratings.dat and movies.dat) and sort the table according `'userId'` and `'Time'` columns. The head of my DataFrame looks like here (all columns values are corresponding to the original data sets):

```
In [36]: df.head(10)
Out[36]: 
        userId  movieId  Rating       Time                         movieName  \
40034        1      150       5  978301777                  Apollo 13 (1995)   
77615        1     1028       5  978301777               Mary Poppins (1964)   
550485       1     2018       4  978301777                      Bambi (1942)   
400889       1     1962       4  978301753         Driving Miss Daisy (1989)   
787274       1     1035       5  978301753        Sound of Music, The (1965)   
128308       1      938       4  978301752                       Gigi (1958)   
497972       1     3105       5  978301713                 Awakenings (1990)   
28417        1     2028       5  978301619        Saving Private Ryan (1998)   
6551         1     1961       5  978301590                   Rain Man (1988)   
35492        1     2692       4  978301570  Run Lola Run (Lola rennt) (1998)   

                            genre  
40034                       Drama  
77615   Children's|Comedy|Musical  
550485       Animation|Children's  
400889                      Drama  
787274                    Musical  
128308                    Musical  
497972                      Drama  
28417            Action|Drama|War  
6551                        Drama  
35492        Action|Crime|Romance  

[10 rows x 6 columns]
```

I can not understand that the same user with user Id 1 see or rated the different movies (Apollo13 (Id:150), Mary Poppins (Id:1028) and Bambi (Id:2018) exactly at the same time (up to the milleseconds). If somebody works already with this data set, please, clear this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter ratings on movie lens, you get pages with 10 movies or so. You set all the ratings, then submit by clicking "next page" or something. 
So I guess all the ratings for the same page are received at the same time, when you submit the page.